# Refactoring CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, refactoring

I have following code:

```
#adminmenu li.hideshow-news, li.hideshow-users, li.hideshow-pages, li.hideshow-gallery, li.hideshow-references, li.hideshow-settings  {
display: none;
font-size: 11px;
background: #fff;
padding: 3px; }
```

I want to achieve (as I tried here) using only one line for diffrent classes on

in div "adminmenu".

How to rewrite this?
Code written above is working only for first class #adminmenu li.hideshow-news, whether other following statments don't.

Do I really need to do:

```
#adminmenu li.hideshow-news {
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
}
#adminmenu li.hideshow-users {
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
}
.....
```

Answer (score 4):

The grouping selector (,) groups *complete* selectors, not partial ones.

```
#adminmenu li.hideshow-news, 
#adminmenu li.hideshow-users, 
#adminmenu li.hideshow-pages, 
#adminmenu li.hideshow-gallery, 
#adminmenu li.hideshow-references, 
#adminmenu li.hideshow-settings  { ... }
```

That said, it might be easier to just say:

```
#adminmenu li { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#adminmenu li.hideshow-news,#adminmenu li.hideshow-users,#adminmenu li.hideshow-pages, li.hideshow-gallery,#adminmenu li.hideshow-references,#adminmenu li.hideshow-settings  {
display: none;
font-size: 11px;
background: #fff;
padding: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
#adminmenu li.hideshow-news, #adminmenuli.hideshow-users, ETC...
{
}
```